# How can I get two lines away out of my collapse bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It is a little bit difficult to show all of my CSS. Because I use Bootstrap.
I have this collapse bar:

[image: it goes about the lines under the brand]

But I don't want that lines, and I also don't know where they come form. So can someone tell me how I get them away here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" onclick="someFunc()">
        <img src="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="Carousel Template for Bootstrap.html" onclick="someFunc()">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Plannen</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" onclick="someFunc()" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Boeken<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Hotels</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Vluchten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Restaurants</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Reis Plannen</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Dingen om te doen/atracties</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/search" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="" class="form-control" placeholder="Wat zoek je?">  
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">zoeken</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="registreren.html" onclick="someFunc()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>acount maken</a></li>
        <li><a href="inlogtemplate.html" onclick="someFunc()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is one of my CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}   
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #FF9900;
}
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #FF9900;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .navbar-brand>li>a {
    color: #FF9900;
    font-size: 22px ;}
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #FF9900;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.dropdown-menu >li>a {color: #FF9900}
```

Comment: Post your main css which you used to style the navbar

Comment: Post a link is probably even faster - that way I wont have to interprete css or alternatively setup a test situation which hopefully will be like your own.

Comment: Use the inspector in chrome to see where those lines are coming from.  Should be pretty easy.

Comment: It worked with the inspector in chrome. Now my lines are gone thanks!!!